# Getting git actions status into Microsoft teams

Tags: git, microsoft-teams, playwright

I want to make a system where I can get the status notification of every git commit. That notification will show the result of the automation test.
The number of total test-cases executed, how many tests failed, how many test passed.
And there will be a summary of it will html, pdf and extent report.

I have tried to achieve it with notify-microsoft-teams. I didnt understand these parts.
But I was able to implement similar thing with other plugin. But this is not what I want to implement for showing my build status.
[notify-microsoft-teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCq7G.png)

Comment: You can create Webhook and select appropriate action like "Workflow runs" or "Workflow jobs" https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks